# Drupal cell spacing

Tags: html, drupal, html-table, padding, cellspacing

Working in Drupal today and simple cell spacing has been anything but simple for me. When I launch the site, my 50px of cell spacing is non existent. I have tried "hspace: 50px", "Border-spacing: 50px" and "padding: 50px" and none of these seem to work.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
<body>
<table class="tablestyle" width="169" border="0" cellspacing="50">
  <tr>
    <td class=><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/helmethub-corporation"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/NameAndLogo2.jpeg" width="91" height="90"/></a>
<a href="http://www.helmet-hub.com/ ">Helmet Hub</a> Social Impact</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/liquiglide"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/LiquiGlide%20logo%20V6%20color.jpg" width="90" height="90"/></a>
<a href="http://www.liqui-glide.com">LiquiGlide</a> High Tech</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/iagree"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/iAgree_LogoSlogan_0.jpg" width="91" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.iagreeonline.com ">Iagree</a> <br />High Tech</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/integralreach"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/IntegralReach1%20vert%20logo%20transparent.png" width="90" height="90"/></a>
<a href="http://www.integralreach.com ">IntergralReach</a>High Tech </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/cellanyx-diagnostics"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/Thumbnail1.jpg" width="91" height="90"/></a>
<a href="http://www.cellanyx.com ">Cellanyx Diagnostics</a> <br />Life Science</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/nordic-technology-group-ntg"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/Logo%20-%20Nordic%20Technology%20Group%20-%20MassChallenge.JPG" width="90" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.nordictechnologygroup.com ">Nordic Technology Group</a><br /> 
High Tech</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/ondeckbiotech"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/Logo_4.png" width="91" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.ondeckbiotech.com ">OnDeckBiotech</a> Life Science</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/recoversorg"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/pic.png" width="91" height="90" /></a><a href="http://recovers.org ">recovers</a> <br />High Tech</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/strong-arm-technologies-inc"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/gradient_2.PNG" width="91" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://Strongarmvest.com">Strong Arm</a> High Tech</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/buysidefx"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/Buyside.jpg" width="91" height="90"/></a>
<a href="http://buysidefx.com ">BuySide</a> <br />High Tech</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/guided-surgery-solutions"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/03_ver%205.jpg" width="90" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.guidedsurgerysolutions.com">Guided Surgery Solutions</a> <br />Life Science</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/nba-math-hoops"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/Math%20Hoops%20logo%20final%20RGB%20031312.jpg" width="90" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://nbamathhoops.org/">NBA Math Hoops</a> <br />High Tech</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/bounce-imaging"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/bounceLogoNew-small.png" width="90" height="91" /></a>
<a href="http://bounceimaging.com/">Bounce Imaging</a><br />High Tech</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/dynamo-micropower"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/Logo%2002_0.png" width="90" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://dynamo-micropower.com/">Dynamo Micropower</a><br />Energy</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/global-research-innovation-technology-grit"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/grit%20logo%20square.jpg" width="90" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://goGRIT.org ">Global Research Innovation & Technology</a><br />Social Impact</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/lovin-spoonfuls-inc"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/LS%20Logo.jpeg" width="90" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.lovinspoonfulsinc.org/">Lovin' Spoonfuls Inc</a><br />Social Impact</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/ministry-supply-inc"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/MOS%20Logo.jpg" width="90" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.ministryofsupply.com">Ministry of Supply</a><br />General</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/ubiqi-health"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/ubiqihealth_logo-inline-cyan_mc.png" width="91" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.ubiqihealth.com">Ubiqi Health</a><br />Life Science</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/windgap-medical-inc"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/logo_large_0.jpg" width="91" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.windgapmedical.com">WindGap Medical Inc.</a><br />Life Science</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/black-island-wind-turbines"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/BlackIsland_WindTurbines_Logo_DRAFT.png" width="91" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.blackislandwindturbines.com ">Black Island Wind Turbines</a><br />Energy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><img src="http://www.capital-market-exchange.com/images/CMX-logo-ls.jpg" width="90" height="23" /><a href="http://www.capital-market-exchange.com/">Capital Market Exchange</a><br />General</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/akrivis-technologies"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/Logo_4color.png" width="91" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.akrivis.com">Akrivis Technologies</a> Life Science</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/neumitra"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/Neumitra_logo.jpg" width="91" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://neumitra.com">Neumitra</a><br />Life Science</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/rallypoint"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/RPlogo.png" width="91" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.RallyPoint.com">Rally Point</a><br />High Tech</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/lab-automate-technologies-inc"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/u23825/LaTech.jpg" width="90" height="90" /></a><a href="http://www.labautomate.net">Lab Automate Technologies Inc</a> <br />Life Science</td>
<td><a href="http://masschallenge.org/profile/coachup"><img src="http://masschallenge.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/spfl_profile_pic/coachup%20logo_jpg.jpg" width="90" height="90" /></a>
<a href="http://www.coachup.com/">CoachUp</a><br />High Tech</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
.tablestyle td {
    padding: 50px;
}
```

(You must apply the padding to the `td` tag as shown in this example.)

If this doesn't work please provide the CSS that you are using.